# Contract does not have fallback nor receive functions

Tags: solidity, fallback-function, receive

In what circumstances a test can fail with the error "Contract does not have fallback nor receive functions" ?

My contract already contains both a fallback and a receive function:

```
event Received(address, uint);
receive() external payable {
    emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

fallback() external payable {

}
```

I am using solodity 0.8.0.

Comment: Calling the wrong contract ? It happened to me once

Comment: Your example compiles just fine when placed inside a contract. Can you provide a self-contained example that reproduces this error when compiled with `solc`?

Comment: What was the test doing? Are you sure the error is related to that contract?